# Not able to delete the registry entry

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I created a new registry entries. I am not able to delete parent node. The structure of registry is as below:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\IE_BACKUP\Internet Settings**
Below is the code I am using for deleting the registry entries. It deletes the content of the node InternetSettings but not able to delete IE_BACKUP.

```
 void main()
 {  //some other stuffs of code are here for creating new registry.
 bool ret = DeleteValueKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\IE_BACKUP",L"Internet  Settings");


 }

bool DeleteValueKey(HKEY hKeyRoot, LPCWSTR Subkey, LPCWSTR ValueKey)
{
HKEY    hKey        = NULL;
bool    bReturn     = false;

    if (RegDeleteKey(hKey, Subkey ) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        bReturn = true;
    }
if (RegOpenKeyEx(hKeyRoot, Subkey, 0, KEY_SET_VALUE , &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{                   
   if (RegDeleteKey(hKey, ValueKey ) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        bReturn = true;
    }
}

if(hKey != NULL){RegCloseKey(hKey);}

return bReturn;
}
```

Comment: What error does it return?

Comment: RegDeleteKey(hKey, Subkey ) returns value 6 i.e ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE.

Comment: Well yeah, because `hKey = NULL;` two lines earlier. When a function does not work, you should double check the parameters.

Comment: Thanks RaymondChen, I changed the parameter to RegDeleteKey(hKeyRoot, Subkey ) and the return value is 5 i.e ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

Comment: The issue is solved thanks all for comment: Just added 
if (RegDeleteKey(hKeyRoot, L"Software\\IE_BACKUP") == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        bReturn = true;
    }
before if(hKey != NULL){RegCloseKey(hKey) and removed from the beginning.

Comment: This code isn't well designed. When an api call fails it needs to bail out immediately.